# Changing directory in python is giving a syntax error

Tags: python, directory

I am following through a Python tutorial (though I have worked with python before) and I seem to be failing at a very simple instruction, namely changing the directory.

When I enter `cd corepy`, or indeed `cd "corepy"` I simply get a syntax error, even though the folder is very clearly there.

Comment: Can you show us the full code that you're running? Or are you literally running ```cd corepy``` as python code? Also, you can use three backticks (`) to format things as code.

Comment: Are you trying to run terminal commands as if they were Python code?

Answer (score 0):

The Python tutorial is telling you where in your terminal to go to. You need to open a terminal and type that in. Or, if you want to know how to do that, it is very simple.

```
import os
os.chdir(corepy)
```

That's all it takes. I hope that helps.